# Appending images using python and imagemagick

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand, bytesio

Most people recommend "wand" when it comes to imagemagick for python but how can I append images using it in python ? I want to add lables to bottom of images using imagemagick in python : http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/ but wand api seems to be very basic and doesn't have lots of imgemagick commands including labels and appending.

Is there any other way to use imagemagick in python ? my images are png type and are BytesIO streams inside the python code not files so I can not pass them to imagemagick using command line and can't save them on any temporary file either.

Comment: See Wand draw text at http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/guide/draw.html#texts

Comment: @fmw42 Yes have seen that but I'm looking for appending a label like the link I've sent, otherwise it would be a lot slower if I want to create an empty image copy my image to top of it create a smaller one for bottom and write text on it and copy to bottom.

Comment: I do not know Wand, but from what I can see you should be able to draw text (or other primitives) directly onto the image using the `with Image` method, specifying the image onto which you want to draw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your asking for, but I'm guessing you want to write a label "below" an image. Here's an example with the [wand](/questions/tagged/wand) library.

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.compat import nested
from wand.color import Color
from wand.font import Font

with nested(Image(filename='logo:'),
            Image(filename='null:')) as (source, text):
    text.font = Font('Impact', 64)
    text.read(filename='label:Hello world!')
    largest_width = max(source.width, text.width)
    offset = (largest_width - min(source.width, text.width)) / 2
    with Image(width=largest_width,
               height=source.height + text.height,
               background=Color('WHITE')) as dst:
        dst.composite(source, 0, 0)
        dst.composite(text, int(offset), source.height)
        dst.save(filename="output.png")
```

[image: Hello World]

**Overview**

```py
with nested(Image(filename='logo:'),
            Image(filename='null:')) as (source, text):
```

Create two images. You would be responsible for replacing `logo:` image with your ByteIO buffer. The `null:` image is a placeholder for allocating a wand instance.

```py
    text.font = Font('Impact', 64)
    text.read(filename='label:Hello world!')
```

This defines the typeface & text to draw. The `label:` protocol can be replaced with `caption:` for additional behavior(s?).

```py
    with Image(width=largest_width,
               height=source.height + text.height,
               background=Color('WHITE')) as dst:
```

Create a third "blank" image that is large enough to include both images.

```py
        dst.composite(source, 0, 0)
        dst.composite(text, int(offset), source.height)
```

Copy the image data from the `source` & `text` to the new image.

Comment: `@emcconville`. Thanks for adding the proper code. I thought it would be possible using Wand, but I am not a Wand user.

Comment: thanks for your code this is very close to what I need and I modified it to my needs (BytesIO) and this example shows exactly why I insisted on using wand, I used this code and the code from Mick_  solution to add same text to same picture, wand(imagemagick) did it in 140ms while PIL took around 900ms.

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick is great but has steep learning curve. You need to have 3rd party ImageMagick installed (Would have to be 32 or 64 bit depending on your version of python). Installation alone is a pain considering you need to add it to path and the executable is necessary to run your script.

Consider something more portable and contained like Pillow which has number of features for achieving your goal.

`pip install pillow`

In pillow you can read images from BytesIO. And also draw or print on them. There is number of options available.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import io


# Reading bytes from file but you can skip that and simply open your bytes like below.

with open('picture.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    draw.text((10,10), "Hello World", fill=(255))
    im.show() # do whatever you like with the image
```

Check the docs for more examples. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/